# Enable auto-build when F5 is pressed and source is out-of-date

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2005, visual-c++

When I press F5 and source was modified, my Visual Studio doesn't rebuild the source and runs the existing (out-of-date) executable. I need to press F7 then F5.

How do I tell msvc to auto-rebuild when I press F5?

This is MSVC 2005, C++.

Answer (score 14):

Tools / Options / Projects and Solutions / Build and Run:

- Before building: Save all changes
- On Run, when projects are out of date: Always Build

Depending on how you have your project dependencies set up, you might need to uncheck "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" as well.

Comment: I changed some of my dependencies around and suddenly F5 for build+run stopped working for me. Your last paragraph was what I was looking for. Thanks!